# Search in one page and show results in other page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I want to implement global search in my project.From any page user can search and he will be redirected to a common page to see the results.
Search key alone should be passed to the new page and the back end call for searching can be done from the new page. Which is the best way to pass search key to the new page? Or should I pass the search results itself?

Comment: Yeah. What have you tried?

Comment: I was passing the search key in url itself

Comment: Sounds like you should make a regular ajax request to the page you want to search, and then go through the response code with js on the same page from which you made the search request.

Comment: Search tag will be from any page and search results I need to show in one common page. If I can pass the search key to the new page I can make the request from there